# Creating A Data Record For a One-to-Many Category Structure With Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new here. With Laravel, I want to save data with multiple selection features. however, the methods in the model file I created do not appear.I'm new to larvae, how can I fix it? I couldn't run the multiple-selection feature.

**Method in controller**

```
public function saveForm()
{
    $movi_name = $req->input('movi_name');
    $release_date = $req->input('release_date');

    $data = array(
        'movi_name'    => $movi_name,
        'release_date' => $release_date
    );

    $categories = request(categories);

    $entry = Movie::insert($data) /*Model File and Save Data*/

    $entry->categories()->attach($categories);
}
```

**Method in my model file**

```
protected $table = 'film';

public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Kategori', 'category_movie');   
}
```

it should be that the selected films have to be included in the categories..  But

> call to member function categories() on boolean

Sorry for bad English

Comment: I think you want Movie::create() not Movie::insert().  It's not saying the method doesn't exist in the class, it's saying that $entry is a boolean, not an instance of Movie.

Comment: yeah, I get it, how can I fix this request?

Comment: Did you try replacing insert with create like suggested?

Comment: I have no idea how to try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you should use `create()` instead of `insert()`.

Using `insert()` will simply return `true` or `false` depending on whether the query was successful or not.

Using `create()` will return an instance of `Movie` model which will have the `categories()` method on it:

```
$entry = Movie::create($data); //<--This is where insert() is replaced with create()

$entry->categories()->attach($categories);
```

---

You will need to make sure that `movi_name` and `release_date` are in the  `$fillable` array in your `Movie` model:

```
protected $fillable = ['movi_name', 'release_date'];
```

Comment: I tried what you said.. this time "General error: 1364 Field 'release_date' doesn't have a default value" ... With this error

Comment: @Atakan Please can you edit your question and all the code for the `Movie` model.

Answer (score 0):

yes I solved the problem

`protected  $fillable = ['movie_name'];`

that was my code.

now that

`protected  $fillable = ['movie_name','release_date'];`